# Concatenate 2 columns Android SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

So far I have this:

```
    Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getAllPatients();
    String[] data = new String[]{DBHelper.KEY_LNAME, 
            DBHelper.KEY_FNAME, DBHelper.KEY_DIAGNOSIS};

    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.fullname, R.id.diagnosis};

    dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_row, cursor, data, to, 0);
    dbHelper.close();

    lv.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

**getAllPatients() method**

```
  public Cursor getAllPatients()
{
    Cursor localCursor = 
            this.myDataBase.query(DB_TABLE, new String[] { 
                    KEY_ID, KEY_FNAME, KEY_LNAME, KEY_DIAGNOSIS }, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (localCursor != null)
      localCursor.moveToFirst();
    return localCursor;
}
```

I want the columns **FNAME**, and **LNAME** to be as one but I'm confused how and where to put the concatenate operator **+** in the String array. Do you have any idea to do this? I would gladly appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: is not an option for you to concatenate in Java side?

Comment: first you should not close cursor which is used in CursorAdapter, next you should do this(concate) in `getAllPatients()` query for `KEY_FNAME + " | " + KEY_LNAME + " AS " + KEY_CONCATED` and use KEY_CONCATED in `data` array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the following when you query

```
Cursor localCursor = 
        this.myDataBase.query(DB_TABLE, new String[] { 
                KEY_ID, KEY_FNAME +"||"+ KEY_LNAME, KEY_DIAGNOSIS }, null, null, null, null, null);
```

And while assigning values using your adapter do as follows,

```
String[] data = new String[]{DBHelper.KEY_LNAME +"||"+ DBHelper.KEY_FNAME, DBHelper.KEY_DIAGNOSIS};

int[] to = new int[] {R.id.fullname, R.id.diagnosis};
```

Comment: @RiyazMuhammed I tried the above example and it worked fine, but how to put a space between the two columns?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT CONCAT(ColA, ColB) AS ColC FROM Table
```

or

```
String query = "select" +ColA+"+"+ColB +"as CompleteAddress from YourTable";
```